# Why doesn't the * apply to the 2nd variable in the list?

Tags: c++

I have the basic C++:

```
int* a, b;
a = new int;
b = a; // invalid
```

However, we all know that this code is invalid. You'd have to write:

```
int *a, *b;  // This is why I "stick" the star to the variable and not the type
             // (why I don't write int* a;)
```

However, if you do

```
typedef int* intPtr;
```

Then you can safely write

```
intPtr a, b;
a = new int;
b = a;
```

Why is that?

As a question of style, should I write `int* a` (because the `*` is part of the type) or should I write `int *a` (to remember that if there's more than 1 variable in the list, you'd need a 2nd * (eg `int *a, *b;`))

Comment: The language is defined this way for historical reasons.

Comment: The syntax of a typedef is like the syntax of a variable declaration. But in place of the name of a variable, you're giving the name of a new type. That type is the same type that a variable would have, had you omitted the `typedef`. Thus, the name you have given the new type refers to the type as a whole, including its level of indirection. And also including array specifiers and function arguments, if any. So the question is more, *why would you expect it to be any different*?

Comment: *As a question of style...*  Put one variable in one statement on its own line.

Answer (score 3):

`int` is a type, while `*` is a [*ptr-operator*](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/dcl.dcl#nt:ptr-operator).  The operators apply to the declarator per [[dcl.decl.general]/2](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/dcl.dcl#dcl.decl.general-2)

> [...] Each declarator specifies one entity and (optionally) names it and/or modifies the type of the specifiers with operators such as * (pointer to) and () (function returning).

So when you have `T* a, b`, `b` doesn't have a *ptr-operator* so it is not a pointer.

When you do `typedef int* intPtr;` you haver now merged the *ptr-operator* to the type, so now `T a, b` applies `T` (`intPtr`) to both `a` and `b`

Answer (score 3):

As you probably know, the reason why `int* a, b;` doesn't make `b` a pointer, is because `*` is grouped with `a`, not with `int`.

The [grammar](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.pre#nt:simple-declaration) calls `int` a *decl-specifier-seq*, and `*a, b` a list of *declarators*. The type of each variable is determined by **combining** information from its respective declarator with the common decl-specifier-seq.

The fact that `*` is a part of the declarator rather than the decl-specifier-seq is caused by the grammar alone. Notice that `intPtr a, b;` is spelled without `*`, and grammatically `intPtr` is decl-specifier-seq, and `a`, `b` are declarators.

Since pointer-ness is now a part of the decl-specifier-seq (rather than the first declarator), it applies to all declarators.

---

> As a question of style, should I write `int* a` ...

This is opinion-based. I personally prefer `int *a` for the reasons you mentioned, but since in idiomatic C++ you rarely declare more than one variable per declaration, `int* a` seems to be getting increasingly popular.